# How to create folder by cell value?

Tags: vba, excel

How would I turn this:

```
 Dim sPath As String
  sPath = "M:\Lvl3-5Mgrs\"
If Len(Dir(sPath & Format(Date, "yyyy_mm_dd"), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
 MkDir (sPath & Format(Date, "yyyy_mm_dd"))
End If
End Sub
```

into a way to create folders by a cell values in a list I put as filename: 
**VBA_2018_Mid_Year_File** list located in sheet("mrkt_leader").

So if I have 10 market leaders in that sheet, I want 10 folders with a market leader having their own folder.

Then how would I have each filtered new file save in that additional folder layer if this is what I have currently?

```
.SaveAs Filename:="M:\Pittsburgh\GRP4\HR_PCorpComp\Retail\!Mid-Year\Mid Year 2018\Reporting\TCR\Lvl3-5Mgrs\" & Format(Date, "yyyy_mm_dd") & "\" & Format(Date, "yyyy_mm_dd_") & Manager, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```

Here's the whole script if that helps (it filters down to specific manager spans based on helper worksheet lists with the managers I want to pick out):

```
    Option Explicit

        Sub Lvl4Mgr()
              Dim Managers, Manager, Leader
              Dim Header As Range, Where As Range, This As Range
              Dim Wb As Workbook

              'Prepare
              Application.ScreenUpdating = False
              Application.DisplayAlerts = False

              'Refer to the headings
              Set Header = Range("A1").EntireRow
              'Refer to all managers in level4
              Set Where = Range("AS2", Range("AS" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
              'Get the managers
              With Worksheets("Lvl4")
                Set Managers = .Range("A2", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
              End With
              'Loop through
              For Each Manager In Managers
                'Find them
                Set This = FindAll(Where, Manager)
                If This Is Nothing Then GoTo Skip
                'Create a new file
                Set Wb = Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet)
                With Wb
                  With .Sheets(1)
                    'Copy the header
                    Header.Copy .Range("A1")
                    'Copy the data
                    This.EntireRow.Copy .Range("A2")
                  End With
                  With .Sheets(1)
                  Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
                  End With
                   Columns("C:C").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
                   Columns("BN:BN").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
                    Rows("1:1").AutoFilter
                 'Save it
                  .SaveAs Filename:="M:\Lvl3-5Mgrs\" & Format(Date, "yyyy_mm_dd") _
                  & "\" & Format(Date, "yyyy_mm_dd_") & Manager, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Password:="Ville18$"
        .Close
                End With
Skip:
                    Next
                    'Done




            End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

could you explain how your data is structured and what do you mean? i.e. are you trying to pick out the managers from the current dataset from another sheet?

generally if you are looping through the list and creating a folder for each you could do something like

```
Dim MainPath As String
Dim ManagerName As String
Dim ManagerFolder As String

MainPath = "M:\Lvl3-5Mgrs\"

With Worksheets("Lvl4")
    For Each Manager In Managers
        ManagerFolder = MainPath & Manager.Value
        If Dir(ManagerFolder, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
            MkDir (ManagerFolder)
        End If
End With
```